# How to translate registration page?

Tags: magento-1.7, localisation, register

so when I click on Register on my site, it leads me to a registration page. And some of the things there are in English (I would like them translated). But I don't see this page in Pages in CMS in Magento. Where can I find this page to edit it? Is there a place where the rest of the pages is, like when you try to order something and you go through the shipping and so on? Where can I find these?

Comment: app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml

Comment: if you have used any template go with template path

Comment: Thanks :). And that's another thing I wanted to ask... How do I get there and edit this file? Is there like an API for that somewhere in Magento? Or do I go to my webhosting server and edit it manually?

Comment: Btw... I'm really new to this and I didn't set up the store. I just have to learn how to manage it, so I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: you can use FTP or otherwise go to server and edit this file

Comment: ohh man, its the knowledge portal every buddy are  wellcome. :)

Comment: if you need more help add me on skype : maitri.infofys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't edit template files to translate strings!**

Magento has a translation system that works on several levels. As a store manager you can change translations using the "Inline Translation" feature.

#### Summarizing the [documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/design/interface-text-change.html?Highlight=inline%20translation):

> 1. **Add Your IP Address to the Developer Mode Whitelist** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 2. **Disable Output Caches** (System > Cache Management)
> 3. **Activate the Translate Inline Tool** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 4. **Update the Text** (Click the [image: book] icon next to any text in the frontend that you want to change)
> 5. **Restore Original Settings**